# Parse server query for object with pointer

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Normally when querying for an object with a pointer I use `query.includeKey("String")`, to be able to access the information that its pointing to in that class.

Recently I needed to access a value from a pointer that was pointed to by another pointer. For example: I have a class in which all likes of a post go to. When a person likes a post I use a pointer to reference the specific post from the Post class which was liked. In my posts class I use a pointer to reference the User class of the user who posted that post. I want to know how I can access that user information from the like class. What I did was I used `query.includeKey("posts")` and then when I try to access say the users picture from the user object I get a crash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `includeKey` for multi-level queries:

```
// Assuming author is the key name in Posts
query.includeKey("posts.author")
```